# Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-task

Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe

**Error trace**

```
System.AggregateException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer8a9e167d-96ee-45c0-9a2c-6251509937e6' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "OpenPolicy failed: 5"
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z  CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z  FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z  ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "OpenPolicy failed: 5"
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable)
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallServiceInternal(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallService(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
2018-09-14T13:25:32.8643473Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "OpenPolicy failed: 5"<---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is thrown when the user is not having full admin rights or does not have right to run service. User must able to set “Log on as a service” rights remotely.

1) Check if the user they are using to connect to remote machine having full admin rights on target machine.

2) If user is already part of for “Log on as a service” and “local admin group” and user used for deployment is local user ( not a domain user ), I will suggest -

```
         1) Try to use the domain join user
```

OR
             2) UAC filtering for local accounts must be disabled to access a remote WinRM service. You can refer this documentation for same. ( more advanced details can found here  “Using Windows Remote Management” )

If this error you are seeing with powershell on remote task, try to make use of latest version 3.* of task, you will not ace this issue

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. We were using a local account on the target server who was also a local admin which should have all been fine. When I specified the account in my pipeline using machinename\username, it did not work.But when I did .\username, it works like a charm. I guess the format domain\username is reserved for account which are actual domain accounts and you cannot for whatever reason specify the servername\username because then it starts looking for the servername part in the AD and obvisouly it ll have no luck there.

Hope this helps some folks.